# how to use the variable by the files in different directory in c++_

Tags: c++, variables

I have a question about the use variables by the files in different directory in c++.

I have a file a.h

```
class A
{
    private:
    B *b_;
}
```

in the file a.cpp, I included the a.h like this #include "a.h"

I have a other file b.h and b.cpp in the same folder as a.h and a.cpp

These is a other file called c.cpp, which is the same level as a.h and b.h,

```
class C
{
   A *a_;
}
```

but the file d.h and d.cpp is in the subdirectory of a.h,b.h,c.h, like this: /(a.h)/(d.cpp, d.h), and in d.cpp, I already included a.h and b.h, but I use it like this way in d.cpp:

```
a_->b_;
```

it shows the following message:

```
warning: statement has no effect
```

how to fix this?

Comment: How do you have access to internet in Prison, T-Bag?

Comment: As it stands, that code does nothing, which is what the warning kindly points out.  What you should do to fix this depends on what you want the code to do.

Comment: also, this has nothing to do with files/directories/..., it is purely code-related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th expression `a_->b_` is just retrieving a value, but not doing anything with it, so as a statement `a_->b_;`, it is not much more useful than e.g. `2;` - you need to do something with it, e.g. assign that somewhere or give it as an argument to some function.

If you don't need an expression for its side effect or for its result, just remove it.

Comment: "you need to do something with it, e.g. assign that somewhere or give it as an argument to some function." why not simply remove it?

Comment: Because I am guessing the original poster wrote it on purpose (but forgot to implement that purpose).

Comment: but even I just a_->b_;, it just access by a pointer, but it still shows this info.

Comment: You probably mean that the compiler is still giving the warning, which is expected. Why do you retrieve a value without using it??? Or are you expecting that the machine will do something magical ?? This is not true in C or C++ (but may be true in Lisp, which has a Read Eval Print Loop)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the effect-less statement.